# Background image in a div to always show a specific portion of image (scaled and positioned)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

An image of size 1900 x 1080 being used in a div as background

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
        html,body {
    height:100%;
}
        #imageHolder{
            background-size:100% auto;
            background-image:url(img/bg2.jpg);
            width:100%;
            height:30%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="imageHolder"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

With my screen size 1366x768 it shows the complete image width but obviously not the complete height. Now the div shows a portion of the image and I want it to show exactly that portion of the image even if I change the browser size. What happens now is if I change the browser size (smaller width than normal) the div gets resized and the image also gets resized however the resized image now shows portion of the image which were not visible before.

How do I get the same portion of the image (nothing less nothing more) just like I get in the maximized browser window.

Comment: You'll way to play with the `background-position` property. By default, images are aligned by top-left, but you can change this to something like `50% 50%` (center/center) or `50% 100%` (center/bottom), etc.

Answer (score 1):

you can add css properties given below to your style sheets

```
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
```

it works fine.I'm added the snippet below.

```css
html,body{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  }
#imageHolder{
           width:100%;
           height:100%;
          /* background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwy2w.jpg");
           background-repeat:no-repeat;*/
  background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwy2w.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed; 
           background-size:cover;
  border:1px solid #000;
           
     }
```

```html
<div id="imageHolder"></div>
```

Comment: This one has the same problem I am facing, when you start resizing the browser window, more image becomes visible, which was not visible before (in full width) until I reduce the browser window to minimum width and then the complete image is shown, I dont want to show those parts of the image (which were not visible before).

Comment: @Novice check now

Comment: No it does not work. It includes more or less image based on the size of the window. I want to show exactly the same image.

Answer (score 0):

```
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
background-position: center center;
```

you can replace center center with top, bottom, left and right to get a more exact part of the image that you want during resize.

Comment: Can it be a specific window in terms of coordinates?

Comment: yep, you can do percentages or even pixels, etc.
if you want more info, have a read here: [link]http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp

Answer (score 0):

The initial layout that you describe has a height / width ratio of

768 window height * 30% height  = 230 px (height)

230 px height / 1366 px width = 0.168

Now, lets set for the div this ratio, using the padding trick:

In this layout, the top of the image will be always shown. This is what you asked, as it is what is seen at the beginning by default.

Just in case you want another part of the image to be seen, adjust background-position accordingly

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  
}
#imageHolder {
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/1900/1080);
  width: 100%;
  height: 0px;
  padding-top: 16.86%;
}
```

```html
<div id="imageHolder"></div>
```

Comment: I think, with your technique, I am close to get what I was looking for. The only problem with this is that it does not show the complete image width. I dont know how but it should show the image (which is bigger than the screen size) scaled to fit in the screen (100% width).

Answer (score -1):

use this

```
#imageHolder{
            background-image:url(img/bg2.jpg);
            width:100%;
            height:30%;
            background-size: cover;
        }
```